# datagridview click event and drag and drop togeder doesn't work - winform

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, drag-and-drop, datagridviewcheckboxcell

I've implemented this simple drag and drop between rows of a `DataGridView` by following this example:
[datagridview-drag-and-drop-rows](https://www.inforbiro.com/blog/c-datagridview-drag-and-drop-rows-reorder)

The grid has a checkbox column (`DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn`) that is no longer clickable after the drag and drop has been implemented.

Maybe the events `MouseMove` and `MouseDown` bypass the checkbox's click, so I have tried to intercept the position of the mouse and get a reference to the underlying control (the checkbox)  and check it programmatically, but without any success.

```
private void dataGridView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)   
 {
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                Control dgrid = sender as Control;
                Point now = dgrid.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
                foreach (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell c in dgrid.Controls.OfType<DataGridViewCheckBoxCell>())
                {
            //check if the point is inside the area

        }

    ...other drag&drop operations
 }
```

But the `dgrid.Controls.OfType<DataGridViewCheckBoxCell>()` seems to not have any cells inside (*obviously there are many*)

Comment: The DataGridView, if you don't add Controls yourself, has two child Controls: VScrollBar and HScrollBar . You probably need `DataGridView.SelectedCells`, if you want to add a range of Cells ([DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewselectedcellcollection)), to the DataObject. So, also change the cast to `var dgrid = sender as DataGridView;`: Control doesn't have SelectedCells.

Comment: @jimi you're right the only two controls the datagrid has are scrollbars! i haven't understood how `DataGridView.SelectedCells()` can be useful to me 

As you said doesn't have selection, `DataGridView.SelectedCells()` but it returns me `null`

Comment: If you want to collect a selection of Cells, you need `SelectionMode = CellSelect`. The first MouseDown, `SelectedCells.Count` always returns `1`. The next MouseDown... Note that `SelectedCells` is set no matter what the SelectionMode is. The settings you choose depend more on what you actually want to Drag/Drop. Do you want to Drag/Drop a selection of Cells or the Rows that own those Cells?

Comment: Following the link to the drag-drop code, I am unable to reproduce what you describe. After moving rows, the check box column remained “checkable/clickable.” Is there something else going on that you are not showing? Again, I am unable to reproduce the problem you describe… _”The grid has a checkbox column (DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn) that is no longer clickable after the drag and drop has been implemented.”_ … my tests show otherwise.